# What am I missing in this highly oscillatory integral?

Tags: numerical-integration, programming, numerics, special-functions, implementation-details

I want to numerically integrate this equation (in python without calling Mathematica):

$\int_0^\infty {\rm d}k f(k) J_v(r k) J_n(s k)$

where $f(k)$ is a non-smooth function, $J_v$ are the Bessel function of the fist kind, and $r$ and $s$ are just constants. In practice I have to integrate

$\int_a^b {\rm d}k f(k) J_v(r k) J_n(s k)$

with usual values for $a \sim 10^{-8}$ and $b \sim 10^{16}$, where $f(k)→0$ for $b≥10^{16}$. I wrote a code based on Levin's [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042794001189) that partially solves my problem, with this method I can integrate up to 50 without much computational power. A exponential change of variables $k=10^u$, helps me to integrate up to $∼10^2$.

Now, I can compute the integral for larger upper limits with more computational power but the error of the integral dramatically increase when I reach $b∼10^3$, pretty far for what I want to do.

I have tested this method in the case where $f(k)=k^{−p}$ and using the analytical solution of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9307213.pdf) and using Mathematica with the following instruction:

```
NIntegrate[f[k]BesselJ[v,r k]BesselJ[v, s k], {k, a, b}, Method -> {"OscillatorySelection", Method -> "LevinRule", "FourierFiniteRangeMethod" -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}}]
```

Clearly Mathematica deals with the integral nicely, much better than my code.

So, my question is: what am I missing? What does Mathetica do that I don't?

Any help or ideas are really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has been a while since I last looked at Levin's paper, but in the meantime: have you seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1186785.1186790)?

Comment: @J. M. Apropos of Levin, I was against him, and on the losing team, in a doubles ping pong game last month.

Comment: @Daniel, As in David Levin of Tel Aviv himself? I didn't know he played table tennis… ;)

Comment: @J. M. Yes, that Levin. Basement [here](http://www.dagstuhl.de/de/programm/kalender/semhp/?semnr=15251)

Comment: @Daniel, that picture looks like a fun bunch. :)

Comment: @J. M. He is in third row from top, second person from left. More or less next to fellow with ball cap (gap with person in front).

Comment: @J. M. Thanks for the reference, very interesting, unfortunately for me I can't wrote f(k) in terms of a polynomial.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, apart from Levin's papers, you might consider looking for papers by Arieh Iserles on oscillatory integration. If all else fails, you can always fall back on Longman's method.

Comment: could you provide specific example values for `r,s,p,v`?

Comment: @J. M., thanks, I will follow your advise.

Comment: @george2079 Typical values are r ~ 0.1, s = [1-10], v ~ 1.5, and I have done tests with p = [1 - 3]